# malloc or _Znwm, which should we use in LLVM IR System

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

While applying for memory in heap in LLVM, we can use `malloc`, but the IR clang++ compiled c++ code, using `_Znwm` (`_ZdlPv` instead of `free`).

Why?  And which one should we choose?

Source Code:

```cpp
class A {
  public:
  A();
  int a;
};

int main() {
  A *a = new A();
  // delete a;
  return 0;
}
```

IR Code;

```cpp
define i32 @main() ... {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca %class.A*, align 8
  ...
  %5 = call i8* @_Znwm(i64 4) #4
  %6 = bitcast i8* %5 to %class.A*
  invoke void @_ZN1AC1Ev(%class.A* %6)
          to label %7 unwind label %8
  ...
```

Comment: Basically, you're asking where `malloc` and `free` should be preferred over `::new` and `::delete`. Note, that this is not llvm related at all. :-)

Comment: So `_Znwm` can be safely used?

Comment: It's a mangled name of `operator new`. If your program requires use of `operator new`/`delete` use that.

Answer (score 1):

`_Znwm` stands for `operator new` (and `_ZdlPv` for `operator delete`):

```
$ echo _Znwm | c++filt
operator new(unsigned long)
```